# Create lambda function to apply to select df columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the following df:

```
id   header1     header2      diabetes obesity hypertension/high blood pressure. . .      
 1  metabolism   diabetes          no      no          no
 2  heart issue  heart disease    None     None        None       
 3    obesity    diabetes          yes     no          no
 4   metabolism  had hypertension  no      no          yes
 5   heart issue heart disease     no      no          yes
 6    obesity    diabetes          yes     yes         no
 7    obesity    diabetes          no      no          yes
```

I want to create a lambda function that iterates through header1 and header2, checks if either cell is a substring of the column names. Depending on whether the column has yes, no, or null, return a column with a flag value.

For every cell in header1 or header2, if it contains a substring match in the column name and there is a yes within that column, flag the new column as 2. If any of the category columns contains a yes, but not a keyword match with header1 and header2, put a 1. Else, leave blank!

Example)

attempt:
cols = [x for x in df.columns if x not in ['header1', 'header2']]

```
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: 2 if df['header1'] or df['header2'] in cols and cols == yes, 1 elif df['header1'] not in df['header2'] in cols and cols == yes, None else
```

desired result:

```
id   header1     header2    diabetes  obesity hypertension/high blood pressure | flag      
 1  metabolism   diabetes         no      no            no                       None                  
 2  heart issue  heart disease  None      None         None                      None
 3    obesity    diabetes         yes     no            no                        2
 4   metabolism had hypertension  no      no            yes                       2
 5   heart issue heart disease    no      no            yes                       1
 6    obesity    diabetes         yes     yes           no                        2
 7    obesity    diabetes          no      no          yes                        1
```

Constructor

Please note that my actual df has a dynamic amount of yes/no columns, but only two header columns.

```
data = np.array([('metabolism','diabetes','no','no', 'no'), 
                 ('heart issue', 'heart disease', None,None,None),
                 ('obesity','diabetes','yes','no','no'),
                 ('metabolism',' had hypertension','no','no','yes'),
                 ('heart issue', 'heart disease','no','no','yes'),
                 ('obesity', 'diabetes','yes','yes', 'no'),
                 ('obesity', 'diabetes', 'no','no', 'yes')])


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['header1', 'header2','diabetes','obesity','hypertension/high blood pressure'])

cols = [x for x in df.columns if x not in ['header1', 'header2']]
```

Comment: `df['header1'] or df['header2'] in cols` doesn't do what you think. It needs to be `df['header1'] in cols or df['header2'] in cols`

Comment: I think you need to brush up on [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create disease column index and disease names series (the latter is used to capture "hypertension").

Then simply apply a function that first counts the "yes" answers and searches for disease names among the "yes" answers

```
headers = ['header1', 'header2']
disease_cols = df.columns.difference(headers)
disease_names = disease_cols.str.split('/').str[0]

def get_flag(row):
    yes = row[disease_cols].eq('yes')
    if sum(yes) > 0:
        return 2 if row[headers].str.contains('|'.join(disease_names[yes])).any() else 1
    else:
        return np.nan


df['flag'] = df.apply(get_flag, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       header1        header2 diabetes obesity hypertension/high blood pressure   flag
0   metabolism       diabetes       no      no                       no           NaN
1  heart issue  heart disease       no      no                       no           NaN
2      obesity       diabetes      yes      no                       no           2.0
3   metabolism   hypertension       no      no                      yes           2.0
4  heart issue  heart disease       no      no                      yes           1.0
5      obesity       diabetes      yes     yes                       no           2.0
6      obesity       diabetes       no      no                      yes           1.0
```

Comment: thanks! going to apply this to my real df tomorrow. I see you separated the header name with the forward slash. Does the snippet above still works for substrings?

for example, if one of my header was lung and the disease column said 'lungs' or 'lung disease', would it be recorded as a yes?

Comment: @Sebazz44 No it wouldn't. That's why I split the column names. If you have column names that partially match with row data, then it's better if you normalize them first (which won't affect the time complexity of your task) so that you can save an extra loop (which will increase complexity) that will be needed otherwise.

Comment: this is actually very close to what I need, but is there anyway it can be altered so if one the headers is like the following:

"the patient had obesity" 

it would parse through the cell and check if every word in the header is in the disease column names?

thats on me for not including a representative example

Comment: @Sebazz44 Yes that will be flagged. `str.contains` is checking if a header contains any disease part of column names (that's why "hypertension" cannot be caught without normalization because "hypertension/high blood pressure" is not contained in "hypertension", the inclusion is the other way around). So if a header had "the patient had obesity" then since it contains "obesity", it will be flagged.

Comment: thank you, I will attempt the solution more generally tomorrow and accept the answer if it works without an issue

Comment: worked well :) thanks a bunch. I have an additional question that I thought of today. ive been trying to figure it out but do you know how to add an additional column to the df which gives the count of matches.

if header 1 has "obesity" and header 2 has "obesity and heart disease", and the disease columns have yes for obesity and heart disease, a column should have "2" on it.

Comment: @Sebazz44 the above function already counts yeses and uses it: `sum(yes)`. Just combine it with the flag value and return a list. Then convert the resulting Series of lists to df columns.